# Python: urllib2 and proxies

Tags: python, proxy, urllib2

I'm trying to write a script in Python that reloads a page every x seconds using a list of proxies, and I'm having an issue at the moment. I know it's not the proxies' faults either, because I can ping them and they return fine. They are HTTP proxies. My script returns this error to me:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
```

I have no idea how to fix it. Here is the actual script:

```
import urllib.request
import time
proxy_list = input("Name of proxy list file?: ")
proxy_file = open(proxy_list, 'r')
url = input("URL to bot? (Has to include http://): ")
sleep = float(input("Time between reloads? (In seconds, 0 for none): "))
proxies = []
for line in proxy_file:
    proxies.append( line )
proxies = [w.replace('\n', '') for w in proxies]

while True:
    for i in range(len(proxies)):
        proxy = proxies[i]
        proxy2 = {"http":"http://%s" % proxy}
        proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler(proxy2)

        opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
        urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
        urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
        time.sleep(float(sleep))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `urllib2`.  Seriously, just don't.

Your holy grail: [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

what you're trying to do is then:

```
while True:
    for proxy in proxies:
        r = request.get(my_url, proxies={'http': proxy})
        print r.text
        time.sleep(float(sleep))
```

Comment: Hm, I just figured out that I think the proxies are the problem.. I'll use `requests` instead of urllib once I get it sorted out.

Comment: Konstantin, given that exception one or more of the proxies is definitely failing to respond. Just use connection timeouts and proper exception handling and the non-functioning proxies shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Does requests support PDF?