# Python urllib2 and SSH proxy -- throws a 404 not found

Tags: python, ssh, proxy, urllib2, python-requests

I'm trying use SSH tunnels inside of Python's urllib2.

---

Creating the tunnel:

```
ssh -N user@machine.place.edu -L 1337:localhost:80
```

- The above line should use `port 80` on the remote machine and `port 1337` on the local machine.
- I used `-N`, so the bash prompt (intentionally) hangs so long as the this tunnel is running.

---

[Using the tunnel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620263/using-an-http-proxy-python) in `urllib2`:

```
import urllib2
url = "http://ifconfig.me/ip"
headers={'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}

proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:1337'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support, urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

req = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
print html
```

**When I run the above code, `html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()` throws the error `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found`.**

**What might be going wrong, and how can we fix it?**

---

Troubleshooting:

- If I turn off the SSH tunnel, the error changes to `urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 61] Connection refused>`. So, Python is clearly "seeing" the SSH tunnel.
- If I comment out the proxy stuff by replacing `opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support, urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1))` with `opener = urllib2.build_opener()`, then the `ifconfig.me` page downloads properly. (Of course, the project that I'm working on requires me to access documents from a few different networks, so I still need proxies to work.)

---

[Some StackOverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175089/python-urllib2-and-proxies) suggest using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead of urllib2. I wouldn't mind using Requests instead -- I just used urllib2 here because I wasn't sure how to do custom headers (e.g. `user-agent`, `referer`) in Requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, since you're the only one with access to `machine.place.edu`, it's going to be impossible for anyone else to reproduce the problem.

First of all, try something like...

```
$ telnet localhost 1337
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET http://ifconfig.me/ip HTTP/1.0
```

...and hit enter a couple of times after the 'GET' line, and see what you get back.

If you get a 404, there's probably something wrong with the proxy.

If you get a 200, then you should be able to recreate that fairly easily with [`httplib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html).

Comment: good thinking. I just tried doing it the `telnet` way, and it also throws a `404`. Any ideas for what could be wrong with the proxy? Also, is there a public machine that I could try this on so any StackOverflow user can reproduce it?

Comment: @solvingPuzzles Are you sure the process running on `machine.place.edu` which is bound to port 80 on localhost actually is a proxy server? Have you ever managed to use it successfully from inside the `place.edu` network? It might just behave differently for connections from the loopback interface, so you could try `ssh -N user@machine.place.edu -L 1337:machine.place.edu:80` to hit it on a different interface.

Comment: It turns out that the problem was with the proxy that I created using `ssh -L`. I'm not sure why that proxy didn't work, but the above `Python urllib2` works fine when using an arbitrary x.x.x.x:80 proxy from a "free proxies online" sort of website.